# Integrate an Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I found this from a derivation from a Dimensional Analysis book.

It starts from the following equation:

$$\frac{d^2(F(x))^2)}{dx^2}+\frac{x}{3}\frac{dF(x)}{dx}+\frac{F(x)}{3}=0$$

where $F(x)$ is a function of $x$

This ODE is then integrated with respect to $x$, and it got

$$\frac{dF(x)^2)}{dx}+\frac{x\cdot F}{3}= \text{const.}$$

where $const.$ should be some terms which the book chooses not to show

I stared at this derivation for a long time, but I could not figure out how this integration makes sense. Please forgive my stupidity if it turns out to be something simple.

Comment: Consider the product rule: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(xf(x)) = f(x)+xf'(x)$$ Can you use this in reverse to integrate the last two terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do integration by part of the second term.

The first term when you integrate becomes $\frac{d(F^2)}{dx}$.

The second term after integration by parts with $u = \frac{x}{3}$ and $dv = \frac{dF}{dx}$

You get $\frac{xF}{3} - \frac{F}{3}$ the last term in this and the last term in the original equation cancels out and you get the final expression .

That is all to it.

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense. It is strange that I thought you cannot just integrate $\frac{d^2(F(x)^2)}{dx^2}$ by "removing" a $dx$, but it seems I am wrong. Nevertheless, I really appreciate your timely answer!

Comment: You are welcome!!

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{xF(x)}{3} \right) = \frac{F(x)}{3} + \frac{x}{3}\frac{dF(x)}{dx}; \tag 1$$

thus the equation

$$\frac{d^2(F(x)^2)}{dx^2}+\frac{x}{3}\frac{dF(x)}{dx}+\frac{F(x)}{3}=0 \tag 2$$

may be written

$$\frac{d^2(F(x)^2)}{dx^2} + \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{xF(x)}{3}\right) = 0, \tag 3$$

or

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{d(F(x)^2)}{dx} + \frac{xF(x)}{3}\right) = 0; \tag 4$$

it then follows immediately that

$$\frac{d(F(x)^2)}{dx} + \frac{xF(x)}{3} = c, \tag 5$$

for some constant $c$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy:  as usual I like your edits, and am learning from them, albeit slowly.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you liked it.